# rstk.ValidationException: Batch imports / Inline edits are not allowed for custom object "Sales Order Line

Tags: trigger

I get these exception error messages when I try to update an object in a test class to test my trigger.

> 14:06:16:525 USER_DEBUG [23]|DEBUG|Test Class Error---Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id a6A70000000GmwKEAS; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, rstk.soline: execution of BeforeUpdate
>
> 00:44:25:000 USER_DEBUG caused by: rstk.ValidationException: Batch imports / Inline edits are not allowed for custom object "Sales Order Line

Here is the trigger:

```
Trigger Sales_Order_Trig on rstk__soline__c ( before update) {
    Try {
        System.debug('***SFDC: Trigger.old is: ' + Trigger.old);
        System.debug('***SFDC: Trigger.new is: ' + Trigger.new);
        //System.debug('begin ' + trigger.new[0].ID);
        System.debug('INstall ID ' + Trigger.new[0].rstk__soline_project__r.Installation__c);

        rstk__soline__c soLine = 
            [select ID, rstk__soline_project__c, rstk__soline_project__r.Installation__r.Account__r.Name,
             rstk__soline_DueDate__c from rstk__soline__c where ID in: Trigger.new];
        system.debug('soline ID ' + soline.rstk__soline_project__c); 
        Id installID = soLine.rstk__soline_project__r.Installation__c;
        system.debug('installID ' + installID);
        Installation__c Inst = [select Id, Account__r.Name from Installation__c where Id = :installID ];

        If (Inst != null) {
            System.debug('The Account Name--' + Inst.Account__r.Name);
            Inst.Scheduled_Start_Date__c = soline.rstk__soline_duedate__c;
            Upsert Inst;  
        } Else {
            System.debug('Else if Null'); 
            //Installation__c InstNew = new Installation__c(Electrical_Install_Complete__c = system.today(),Panel_Install_Complete__c = Date.today(), Building_Permit_Submitted_Date__c = Date.today(), Inverter_2_Type__c = 'Acme Inverter3000', 
            //                                         Inverter_3_Type__c = 'Acme Inverter3000', Inverter_4_Type__c = 'Acme Inverter3000');
            //Insert InstNew; 
        }        
    } catch(Exception e) {
        system.debug('Exception--- ' + e);
    }    
    system.debug('Sales_O_Trig End');    
}
```

Here is the test class:

```
public class TestException extends Exception {}

static testMethod void positiveTest() {
    Try {
        system.debug('before soline assign');
        rstk__soline__c soLine = [Select ID,rstk__soline_DueDate__c From rstk__soline__c
                                  where rstk__soline__c.rstk__soline_project__r.Installation__c = 'a067000001DiN0CAAV' limit 1];
        system.debug('after soline assign');               

        soLine.rstk__soline_DueDate__c = Date.today();
        system.debug('testTrig soline duedate ' + soLine.rstk__soline_DueDate__c);
        update soLine;        
    } Catch(Exception e) {        
        System.debug('Test Class Error---' + e.getMessage());
        Throw e;
        //return;
    }
    system.assert(true); 
}
```

When I look at the debug log after I run the test class the trigger appears to run fine but when it returns to finalize the update I get the error as described previously.  Everything I read online points me in the direction of permissions set on the Sales_Order_Line object which I checked but please refresh my memory if you know where they can be adjusted.  I believe there isn't any restrictions on updating this object.  Also I don't know if this matters but there are 2 other triggers on the object as well that I didn't create but they seem to work fine. Please help I have spent too much time on this as it is.

Comment: I think there is something outside of the code you included that is causing this issue. Do you have another trigger that could cause it? Vould you add a few more line from the debug -- the 10 lines or so before the "Test Class Error ---" error?

Comment: 22:06:41:000 LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS 22:08:08:006 CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE_END 22:08:08:006 CODE_UNIT_FINISHED Sales_Order_Trig on soline trigger event BeforeUpdate for [a6A70000000GmwK] 22:08:12:824 ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG rstk
22:08:12:956 DML_END [17]|
22:08:12:956 EXCEPTION_THROWN [17]|System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id a6A70000000GmwKEAS; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, rstk.soline: execution of BeforeUpdate 22:06:41:000 EXCEPTION_THROWN I checked the other trigger and it seemed to work fine but I could be wrong so I am open to any suggestions.